# High CPU Usage in windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance, central-processing-unit, cpu-usage

In one of our production servers the CPU usage is 100% and thus some of the backup jobs failed.
In windows server 2003 cms.exe shows : 50%, tomcat_3.exe : 25%, and tomcat_1.exe : 25%.
Please help me how can I overcome this issue.
Attached Process log.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @pst Its look odd, in stack-overflow or any-other sub-network, can I ask this question? If cms.exe comes down to a 49% then either tomcat_3.exe or tomcat_1.exe will become 26% to make it 100%. And lots of backup jobs are failing. Admin/system guys also not getting enough idea on this. Thanks.

Comment: I just restarted all my tomcat related services, and all the reporting services. tomcat_1.exe and tomcat_3.exe now showing 0 CPU usage. However CMS.exe still shows 50. And another process System Idle Process now showing 50. Though CPU usage now came down to 50% compared to our previous 100%. Any ideas to get rid off that 50% used by CMS.exe?

Comment: Don't worry regarding System Idle Process - it shows how many percentage of resources is free. System Idle Process 99% CPU indicates no other process is running in the CPU.

Comment: Thanks @inhabitant for your information. However that 50% is still a problem. I am not sure what is CMS.exe process does in a system? Is it possible for me to End process?

Comment: cms.exe is a process belonging to product BusinessObjects Enterprise and the 1st link in google points to [this](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=516407&sid=856993ad3da114d8b45aa0695acfe0e7) article. I actually have no experience working with this and whouldn't kill process right way. If you have someone(colleagues/senior sysadmins) to ask - this is proper time to do so.

Comment: Thanks we just killed the process and restarted the service. And everything looked normal now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem we got from the event log. Because of low memory the cms.exe attempted auto shutdown, couple of days before. However that auto shutdown did not happened successfully and the process status locked at stopping. Hence the process took lot of CPU. And we had only one option that to kill the process and restart the service Central Management server from services.msc. Now looks like all set. Thanks a lot for all your help and useful tips. SIBS.